# Potentiometer partial range usage

Tags: voltage-divider, potentiometer

I have a 100k ohms potentiometer. My problem is that I have a control stick that goes from left to right representing a very small angle - corresponding to 618 ohms of the potentiometer's range. So within the first 618 ohms, I want to reach the value of 5V.

What electronics should I add to achieve this result, please?

[image: original diagram]

---

**Update**

Implementing [Spehro's suggestion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/535406) - will this be suitable, knowing that the max value will be reached at 61mV?

[image: schematic]

---

Below is [Math's solution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/535399):

[image: schematic]

---

Which of the two solutions is the best, please?

Comment: If your pot is 10 watt rated and capable of surviving a thousand volts across it then it can be done.

Comment: You are talking about using 0.62 percent of the full range of the pot. If the full range is 270 degrees of movement, that would be less than two degrees.

Comment: Yes, Solomon, this is exactly my issue.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by using such a small portion of the POT range?

Comment: This value corresponds to the max displacement of a control rod.

Comment: @AACES - Hi, I recommend you take a step back & consider other options as well, if you are only considering using a potentiometer rotating 2 degrees. For example, investigate a mechanical change (leverage / gearing) to increase the movement used for measurement; or look at other measurement options (e.g. optical encoder) more suitable for measuring small movements. This *might* be an "[XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/)" where the proposed solution (potentiometer rotating less than 2 degrees) has been chosen too early, and re-evaluating a greater range of possible solutions would be better.

Comment: Your op-amp circuit allows the '+' input of the op-amp to be driven to a higher voltage than the 5V supply. I'm not an expert, but that sounds like a Bad Idea. You should be able to design a circuit in which the op amp is powered by the same 10V supply that supplies the potentiometer, but which limits the output voltage to +5V.

Comment: You could use more of the potentiometer's range if you use gears to amplify the motion of the control. Though the backlash might be unacceptable with such a small range of motion.

Comment: Another note: Depending on the specific op-amp that you use, it will be tricky or impossible to drive the output all the way down to the negative supply voltage. Since the "negative" supply is connected to ground (0V), you should not expect to be able to turn the output all the way down to zero.

Comment: @Hearth, not practical, for reasons that Spehro Pefhany mentioned. Even if the gear train had zero backlash (which, it won't), precise, smooth control over such a small range of motion of the pot shaft will not necessarily give you precise, smooth changes in the output voltage.

Comment: So let me try and tackle this XY problem...

My initial need is as follows. Read the 5 controls from a helicopter simulator (seat), which can be compared to a joystick. Since the "seat" uses HID protocol through a USB port, my idea was to use the potentiometer instead since this protocol is totally unknown to me. Reading all your advice, I will either use gears to make better use of the potentiometer range or look into the optical encoder.

Answer (score 2):

Well, usually it's a very bad idea to use such a small part of a potentiometer element. There may be mechanical travel that has no electrical effect, and the position of the wiper will become extremely sensitive to motion, temperature, vibration etc.

Anyway, you can add an amplifier to the output. To take 61.8mV and output 5V, you'd need a gain of about +80.9. The op-amp should have low Vos for the results to be useful.

Even though this answers your question, I suspect this will be of no benefit to  you. You might want to explain your actual problem. If you are trying to get a measurement of a small displacement with a pot that has a large motion, this method will likely not be of much use unless  you've got something like a 10 turn helical coil pot with a hybrid element.

Comment: Thank you Spehro. My problem is that I have a control stick that goes from left to right representing a very small angle - corresponding to 618 Ohms. The potentiometer has a precision of 2%. Can this cover the mechanical travel you were talking about? If not what system can I use, please?

Comment: Can you link the specifications? Usually 2% means 2% of full range (100K)  or 2K, so 600 ohms would be lower than that.

Comment: Here is the datasheet: https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/3549.pdf

Comment: Well, that's a 10 turn pot with a helical element and there is a hybrid option available. The non-hybrid option has resolution of .008% so you'd get 50 or 100 steps in the small angle. So the amplifier might work for you.

Comment: Sorry, Spehro but I do not see the non-hybrid variant you have spotted. And being between 0 and 61mV max, won't I be too sensitive to noise?

Comment: The  Hybritron® ones are hybrid. Other ones are not. I don't think noise will be the biggest problem.

Comment: What do you foresee as being the biggest issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your output voltage will be \$V_{OUT}=V_{CC}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$
To obtain a 5V output with a \$V_{CC}=10V\$ requires that \$R_1=R_2\$, i.e. the midpoint of your potentiometer.